# How to organize my flask project properly?

Tags: python, flask

I'm writing my blog project by flask and sqlalchemy, but I don't know how to organize it.Here is is the file tree:
[image] 
the admin and main are two blueprint, I create my app in the blog's **__init__.py**.
But where should I create my models and how to use it correctly?[image]

Can I create an engine instance and make it global? So that everytime I need to connect to database, I just need to make a new session and bind this engine? Or should I establish new connection and engine for every request?

Comment: for database handling, have a look at [Flask-SQLAlchemy extension](http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.1/). It handles the SQLAlchemy engine operations and many other things for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally prefer the global instance method for two reasons. First it can reduce the handshake cost since it's a long-live connection. Second, it can easily transform into a connection pool.

Comment: But there is another problem, how can I make it global and single?If I created a new engine in an independent file,import this file in the admin's and main's views.py, that will lead to multiple import.How can I avoid it?

Comment: Short story is Singleton(pleae google singleton python). Long story, if you use flask-sqlalchemy equivalent wrapper, please refet to [Flask-SQLAlchemy](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask-sqlalchemy/blob/master/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py#L531) and pay special attention to line 535,536,543,547.

Comment: your answer really helpful